# Does gpu rendering support on gt 730 ddr3 or gt730v2 ddr5?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have an old pc core 2 duo E6550,Ram 4gb,i know this is not a power full pc.Does gpu rendering support these two graphic cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) in the blender reference manual they claim that

> We support graphics cards starting from GTX 4xx (computing capability 2.0).

I also found both the cards you mentioned in the list of CUDA-enabled GeForce products on [this NVIDIA page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with computing capabilities listed as 2.1 and 3.5 so I would claim that yes, GPU-rendering does supports those cards, especially the ddr5-model.